# Webaccessibility - Suggestions needed

Tags: php, javascript, html, xhtml, accessibility

Visiting the following site in IE:

http://www.oebb.at

In the header section one can see the plus(+) symbol. By clicking on it the the font size and the images will be enlarged. And similarly clicking on (-) symbol the sizes will be reduced.

I would like to know what will be the best way to implement it in my website.

Similarly, pressing Alt + 0 one sees an options list to directly access different areas of the website.
For example by pressing Alt+2 the search field will be focused. And by pressing Alt+1 the main menu will be focused.

What is the best possible way to implement this?

Comment: Javascript enables you to do so ... check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237373/jquery-handling-multiple-key-presses-in-ie-and-firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Alt+[key] is called an access key. Access keys are part of the [html specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.2) and can be placed behind form elements and hyperlinks:

```
<a href="index.html" accesskey="h">Home</a>
```

All modern browsers support access keys and at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key) you can find a list which key combination triggers an access key.

About the fontsize: you should trigger it with javascript. Clicking on the "+" will set a property, clicking on the "-" reverts this change. For example, you can set a class to your  element. In jQuery:

```
$("#increase").click(function() {
    $("body").css("font-size", "1.2em");
});
```

You can increase the fonts by using font-size in css (percentages or em) or use classes, for example "smallest", "small", "normal", "large" and "largest".

Answer (score 3):

**font size**

If true accessibility is the concern, create the web pages so that the user can change the default text size using the text resize controls of their web browser. Otherwise you can [use JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+change+text+size) (or a server side option like PHP) to write out styles in the web page. A search on the web will get you 100's or more examples of how to do it either way.

**accesskeys**

For the alt-key-shortcuts, you can use the [HTML accesskey attribute](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/accesskeys).